# Get data attributes with Nokogiri

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri, custom-data-attribute

I'm scraping a site that has a number of divs with the same ".pane" class and same "data-pane" data attributes.

```
input = doc.css('.pane[data-pane]')
```

How do I filter or select from the above to get the div which has a "data-pane" attribute equal to a specific value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just treat it as you would any other attribute with the usual CSS syntax:

```ruby
input = doc.css('.pane[data-pane="the value"]')
```

Comment: Aww thanks, did not realise it was that straightforward.